# Anyone heard of a custom report builder program?

Tags: database, reporting

I'm looking for a program to create and store custom reports.  What I want to be able to do is build a report by adding fields for end users to fill out and then have the program create the appropriate database (or update the appropriate database table rows).  So, just a simple report that can be created entirely by an end user from the front end.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
Just to clarify, the program must

1. Generate a data entry form
2. Create some sort of data structure to store the information from the form
3. Create a report that displays the form data

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information. What database server are you using for starters?

Comment: Are you sure, that the report builder should create the database/database rows? Generally, the first tool that I'm thinking of, when hearing the word 'report' is BIRT http://www.eclipse.org/birt

Comment: Isn't this what Crystal Reports does?

Comment: @Joe: It certainly does, but it has a "nice" price tag (about EUR 2000 for a developer advantage runtime license)... since BIRT is open source, I'd check it out first.

Comment: A "reporting" product isn't typically also going to help you create data-entry forms, which it sounds like you're also asking for when you say "have the program create the appropriate database (or update the appropriate database table rows)." - So, are you looking for a report generator, or a data-entry form generator, or both?

Comment: ok, I understand a bit more now.  mfinni is right, it must generate a data entry form, and then create reports that match that form.  To my knowledge, crystal reports can not do this.  CR can show database info, but it won't let you add data from its front end.  As for BIRT, it looks very cool, perhaps better than Crystal Reports but I don't think it solves my issue of data-entry/form generation

Comment: OK - so you actually need something that will create data structures in the DB, not just let an end-user insert rows (data entry?) You're asking for ...I don't know what, exactly. Sounds like you need to pick an application-builder framework. I worked on something like this with Service-Now.com - it's a hosted customizable web app for Service management. As an admin of the system, I could create new forms and reports from the web interface. They built their own framework to accomplish this though. I'm not even sure what you could use off-the-shelf.
Please describe the actual business need?

Comment: Actually, @Bob Rivers below sounds like a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since the users will need to "fill out" and you didn't narrowed your need, I understand that you can use even a CMS like Drupal.

With Drupal (and some modules like webform, cck, views) users will be able build their on questionnaires, collect data, and then export it if it's necessary.

By doing it this way, we'll not need to deal with "database stuff". It will manage it for you.

Comment: As I mentioned above, now that the poster has clarified his needs, something like this is probably what's called for.

Comment: hmm...this seems like it could be something along the lines of what I was looking for.  I will try it out in more detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds perhaps a bit like something you could twist [limesurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/) to do.

Answer (score 0):

It’s really powerful, flexible Mac database: FileMaker. The Pros have it - evaluation from [www.filemaker.com](http://www.filemaker.com/).

Comment: FileMaker is not restricted to Macs.

Comment: Nor is FileMaker "really powerful". I'd rank it up there with MS Access, enough features that people who don't know what they're doing commonly abuse it and create unmaintainable nightmares.